# Finding area of a triangle with integration

Tags: integration, triangles, coordinate-systems, area

I have a triangle with coordinates (0,0), (1,2) and (1,0).
Is the area of this triangle same as finding the integral of the function $y=2x^2$ and substituting the value of x=1 and y=2? Because what i understood by reading about integral is that it can find the area under the slop with which the function to be integrated is defined. I have tried this way and i am getting different values for the integration method and original area. Where am i wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function to integrate is $y=2x$, not $y=2x^2$. The hypotenuse is a straight line, not a parabola. And you integrate between 0 and 1. Draw a figure. It will help you understand.

Comment: ok. i got it. thanks. i will not be measuring the area of triangle with y=2x^2.